# What is the difference between app:contentPadding and android:Padding?

Tags: android, padding, android-cardview, cardview

I have a `CardView` and inside that there is a `TextView`. I am trying to add padding in card view. But when i use `android:Padding="16dp"` nothing happens between the textview and `Cardview` while when i use `app:contentPadding="16dp"` the `16dp` space is created between the `CardView` and `TextView`.
Why is this happening?

Comment: There's a brief reference to this in the `CardView` docs (5th paragraph): https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/cardview/widget/CardView

Answer (score 1):

You can check the [javadoc](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/cardview/widget/CardView):

> Since padding is used to offset content for shadows, you cannot set padding on `CardView`. **Instead, you can use content padding attributes in XML or `setContentPadding(int, int, int, int)`** in code to set the padding between the edges of the `CardView` and children of `CardView`.

Answer (score 0):

ContentPadding is a typealias for **EdgeInsets** which is used to Describe set of offsets from each of the **four sides of a box**.

EdgeInsets (float top, float left, float bottom, float right)